# Capture exit code and output of a command

Tags: shell, command-substitution, exit-status

I'd like to do:

`1.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
r=0
a=$(./2.sh || r=$?)
echo "$a"
echo "$r"
```

`2.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo output
exit 2
```

But it outputs:

```
$ ./1.sh
output
0   # I'd like to have `2` here
```

Since `$(...)` runs a separate shell. So, how do I capture both, exit code and output?

Comment: a=$(./2.sh); r=$?;  ## doesn't work?

Comment: The reason `1.sh` has an exit code of 0 not 2 is because `echo "$r"` is a command that exits 0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The exit code of a process calling another process is the one of the called process.

```
$($($($($(exit 2)))))
echo $?
2
```

*Here there are 5 levels of calling.*

In your case:

```
r=0
a=$(./2.sh)
r=$?
echo "$a"
echo "$r"
```